# www-data cannot use aws command

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have some php that executes a .sh which is has some aws s3 cp commands among other things.

However when this script is executed by www-data the aws command is not found. I suppose this is because I installed using `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` so it is now installed under the user "test". The script runs fine when calling it from the CLI with the test user.

How can www-data use the `aws` command? Should I just install without --user?

Comment: Yes, or `sudo su www-data` and install it under them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem correct. Making awscli binaries available for www-data should fix the problem. The easiest way would probably be to install the aws cli for www-data user or you may also try option 2 from [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/10086) link.